# Unable to parse numbers with \addplot table

Tags: pgfplots

I have a .csv file with numbers like "76.755,63" and can't figure out how to plot them. I tried:;

```
/pgf/number format/read comma as period,

/pgf/number format/1000 sep = {\.},

/pgf/number format/set thousands separator = {\.},
```

in all kinds of combinations but always get an error like:

"Could not parse input '76.755,63"... "The unreadable part was near ',63"...

So if someone knows how to do this, please let me know...

Comment: The last two of those are the same, but they are only related to output, to number printing. To read commas as decimal points `\addplot table[/pgf/number format/read comma as period] {filename.csv};` works, but in your case that wouldn't be enough, as it would give you two decimal separators. I would edit/re-generate the `csv` using a more sensible format, i.e. `xxxxx.yy`, no thousands separator, and period as decimal separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a pure latex solution for this. Latex is very sophisticated for representation but seems to fail with conversion problems like this. I used a python script to convert the number format after your approach.

Comment: That is often a better solution. It might be doable in lualatex, but writing a python preprocesser is often faster, and good programming practise

Comment: TeX hence LaTeX can definitely do these conversions. You only need to push a feature request to pgfplots' maintainer ... https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots